# How to get the products according to price selected in custom post type?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type named tea and inside this i created a custom field tea_price.Now, I created price range slider in frontend and when i select the range through sliding, i got minimum and maximum value.Now, I created meta_query to show all products that start from minimum value to maximum value.

```
$args['meta_query'] =   array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                       'meta_key' => 'status_tea',
                                       'value' => 'available',
                                       'compare' => '='
                                     ),
                                array(
                                       'meta_key' => 'price_tea',
                                       'meta_value' => $teaMinAmt,
                                       'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                                       'compare' => '>=',
                                     )
                        );
```

I am trying by this query but not getting correct result. Can anyone tell what i need to change to get the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

According to Codex [Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query), when you use keys from Meta_Query in array, they must be named `key` and `value`, but you use `meta_key` and `meta_value` in one of the arrays, and `meta_key` and `value` in the other.

Also, check `meta_name` key. In your description you say that you use a custom field with name `tea_price`, but in the provided query code you refer it as `price_tea`.